# Loading custom markers with image in google map using glide image library not working properly

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I am trying to load more than one custom markers with image using the glide library. 
Currently it is displaying only the last marker. But, I want to display multiple markers. How can i fix this problem?

The lat, long, and the image (image url) for showing the markers are taken from the server.

Following is my code:

```
 private void getZoom(List<Member> memberdata) {
        try {
            mMap.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < memberdata.size(); i++) {

                Member members = memberdata.get(i);
                name = members.getMemberName();
                double latittude = Double.valueOf(members.getLat());
                double longitude = Double.valueOf(members.getLong());
                loc = new LatLng(latittude, longitude);
                String ImageUrl=members.getImageUrl();
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(ImageUrl)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .fitCenter()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true)
                        .transform(new CircleTransform(Main2Activity.this))
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                Marker startPerc=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(loc)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(mCustomMarkerView, bitmap))));
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13f));
                              markers.add(startPerc);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,String.valueOf(e),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                System.out.println("exception"+e);
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin))
                                        .position(loc));
                            }
                        });

            }
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (Marker marker : markers) {
                builder.include(marker.getPosition());
            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            int padding = (int) (80 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
            mMap.moveCamera(cu);
            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Server response:

```
{
  "groupName": "Friends",
  "members": [
    {

      "imageUrl": "http://xxxxxxxx/get-profile-picture",
      "lat": 8.560408,
      "long": 76.880284
    },
    {

      "imageUrl": "http://xxxx/3031957896_bc7ef6918c.jpg",
      "lat": 8.558097,
      "long": 76.88156
    },
    {
      "imageUrl": "http://xxxxxx/PassPort-Size-Photograph-768x954.jpg",
      "lat": 8.5604818,
      "long": 76.8802502
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your server is sending different locations? can you post your server response?

Comment: {
  "groupName": "Friends",
  "members": [
    {
     
      "imageUrl": "http://xxxxxxxx/get-profile-picture",
      "lat": 8.560408,
      "long": 76.880284
    },
    {
      
      "imageUrl": "http://xxxx/3031957896_bc7ef6918c.jpg",
      "lat": 8.558097,
      "long": 76.88156
    },
    {
      "imageUrl": "http://xxxxxx/PassPort-Size-Photograph-768x954.jpg",
      "lat": 8.5604818,
      "long": 76.8802502
    }
  ]
}

Comment: it makes much sense that you only see the last one.. one question: what's the size of your `markers` list? (considering that you don't add markers to the list when fetching the image fails)

Comment: Also one more suggestion: avoid animating the map everytime you add a new marker since you will do it eventually once all marker will be displayed